# c++ constant pointer in the constexpr class

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constexpr

Good day! Please help me for my code, I try to make constexpr class with const pointer to non-constant and change non-constant variable in future, my compilator says

`"error: ‘Actuator{const Pin{1ul, 1ul}, const Pin{1ul, 2ul}, const Pin{1ul, 3ul}, ((velocity_type*)(& velocity))}’ is not a constant expression"`,

Object act1 always life, because its code for ARM embedded device

Code:

```
#include <cstddef>

typedef std::size_t port_type;
typedef std::size_t pin_type;
typedef std::size_t velocity_type;

class Pin {
private:
    port_type const _port;
    pin_type const _pin;

public:
    constexpr Pin(port_type const port, pin_type const pin) :
            _port { port }, _pin { pin } {
    }
};

class Actuator {
private:
    Pin const _enable_pin;
    Pin const _dir_pin;
    Pin const _step_pin;
    velocity_type* const _velocity; //constant pointer to non-constant variable

public:
    constexpr Actuator(Pin const ep, Pin const dp, Pin const sp, const velocity_type velocity) :
            _enable_pin { ep }, _dir_pin { dp }, _step_pin { sp }, _velocity(const_cast<velocity_type*>(&velocity)) {
    }
    void set_velocity(const velocity_type velocity) const {*_velocity = velocity;} //try to change velocity
};

int main() {
    constexpr Actuator act1 ( Pin { 1, 1 }, Pin { 1, 2 }, Pin { 1, 3 }, 1u );
    act1.set_velocity(1u);
}
```

Comment: Even if your compiler allowed to change the value the pointer pointed to, doing so would be _undefined behavior_ anyway (because it contains a dangling pointer to the value which doesn't exist anymore).

Comment: my guess is that the statement flagged as an error does not satisfy the required compile time evaluation.  Have a look at this:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to c++ standard [[expr-const]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const#2) (emphasis mine)

> An expression e is a core constant expression **unless** the evaluation of
>   e, following the rules of the abstract machine, would evaluate one of
>   the following expressions:
>    (...)
>   15. a reinterpret_­cast

`((velocity_type*)(& velocity))` is definitely a form of reinterpret casting so it cannot be used in constant expression...